# Regex: How to Display 4 digits after the "L" (same for after the "C") ? like : L100_C1_"1"_KO,L100_C2_"3260"_KO,etc

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation

Hi Every Regex Expert,

I have one Array List al1 like this (line by line):

*al1 : L1_C1_0, L1_C2_"11229", L1_C2_"CHK_CASHING"_OK, etc... L1_C100_"FR45248624892", L2_C1_0, L2_C2_"11229", L2_C2_"CHK_CASHING"_OK etc... L2_C100_"FR45248624892"_KO, L3_C1_0, L3_C2_"11229", L3_C2_"CHK_CASHING"_OK etc... L3_C100_"FR45248624892"_KO, L4_C1_0, L3_C2_"11229", L4_C2_"CHK_CASHING"_OK etc... L4_C100_"FR45248624892"_OK*

I write this regex but it doesn't work as i want :

*String spattern = "(L(([1-9]?[0-9])|100)_C\\d_\\W.*?L\\2_C\\d{3}_\".*?\"(?:,?\$?))";*

I want to display like this :

L1_C1_0, L1_C2_"11229", L1_C2_"CHK_CASHING"_OK, etc...L1_C100_"FR45248624892"

L2_C1_0, L2_C2_"11229", L2_C2_"CHK_CASHING"*OK etc...L2_C100*"FR45248624892"_KO

L3_C1_0, L3_C2_"11229", L3_C2_"CHK_CASHING"*OK etc...L3_C100*"FR45248624892"_KO

L4_C1_0, L3_C2_"11229", L4_C2_"CHK_CASHING"*OK etc...L4_C100*"FR45248624892"_OK

L5_C1_1 etc...

Some one can help me to Display this ?

Thank you very much for help

Comment: What do you want to match? Something like this? `\bL(?:[1-9]\d?|100)_C\d+_(?:\"[^\"]*\")?\w*` https://regex101.com/r/wWQPdC/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you're pattern didnt work. I would like to cut line by line this ArrayList (al1) after the comma. For example L1_C1_"blablabla"_ok

Comment: What exactly did not work? Can you be more specific, or update the question? What is the tool or language?

Comment: For example L1_C1_"blablabla"_ok, L1_C2_"kuhkhd"_KO... (then my pattern must to cut if it's encounter L2_C1_"kuhilj"_ok) same thing for L3_C1_"hkbhgcd"_ok etc... L102_C1 etc...L220_C1...) 4 digits for after the L and the C please. Tool is Katalon and language is Java